# Text in span tag and nested span tag not showing

Tags: html, css

I previously asked a similar question, but I did more research and found the more specific issue. I want to show text inside the span tag so that the div elements also inside it (which each has a checkbox) show up on the screen.

I tried adding a test image inside both the first and second span tag and it shows on the screen. But the text in both is not showing. It should show up as "Countries **+**" in the `checkbox-div` box. When I put the image inside `location-div` the image does not display. The only thing that shows up is the button-like "Clear" reset element. As in this picture:
[button-like element with "Clear" label inside checkbox-div bordered box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1SuB.png), despite it showing in the running code snippet.

I also tried adding `style='display:block'` inside all span tags. Then I tried adding that inside only the inner span tags as an answer to a question suggested, but it didn't work either.

```js
function expand(element) {
  var list = element.nextElementSibling;
  var symbol = element.firstElementChild;
  if (list.style.display == 'block') {
    list.style.display = 'none';
    symbol.innerHTML = '+';
  } else {
    list.style.display = 'block';
    symbol.innerHTML = '&minus;';
  }
}
```

```css
#checkbox-div {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.location-div {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.expand {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand-symbol {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id='checkbox-div'>
  <form id='location-form' action="javascript:void(0);">
    <span class='expand' onclick='expand(this)'>Countries 
            <span class='expand-symbol'>+</span>
    </span>
    <!-- begin long line -->
    <div class='location-div'>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Albania' class='location-checkbox'><label for='Albania'>Albania</label>
      <br>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Algeria' class='location-checkbox'><label for='Algeria'>Algeria</label>
      <br>
      <!-- Etc. other countries -->
      <br>
      <input type='checkbox' id='Zimbabwe' class='location-checkbox'><label for='Zimbabwe'>Zimbabwe</label>
      <br>
    </div><input type='reset' value='Clear'>
    <!-- end long line -->
  </form>
</div>
```

There is that very long line with line breaks because it is created in a for loop and with echo's in php before and after the loop, I added the paragraph spaces so it's easier to read.

The expand function that once the "Countries **+**" is clicked, should show all the checkboxes underneath "Countries **-**". This function works on another page that I tested, but I haven't been able to test it on the page I'm working on yet since "Countries **+**" doesn't show, despite it working in this code snippet.

Comment: `nextSibling` might not be what you think it is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling#Notes

Comment: I turned your HTML, CSS and JS into a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you.

Comment: @Cbroe I changed it to nextElementSibling but it still does not show "Countries +" on my page. I edited my code to show that.

Comment: Showing/hiding the checkboxes appears to work fine now (tested in Chrome and Firefox), so what is the issue now?

Comment: @CBroe, in the code snippet yes but I added a picture of what I'm seeing on the actual page I'm working on and "Countries +" is not appearing above the "Clear" box.

Comment: You must have some css that is hiding the `expand` span.

Comment: @Dionys Thanks, I see it now! I started taking out extra details from the css and turns out the min-width: 1010px; in body{} was hiding it. Though I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

nextSibling returns any next text node, comment node, or element node, thanks to Cbroe who pointed that out in the comments. I changed it to nextElementSibling to only get the next element.

Also thanks to Dionys who made me realize it had to do with some css hiding the expand. My body css was originally like so:

```
body{
    min-width: 1010px;
    font-size: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

When I removed `min-width: 1010px;` the text in the span showed up now.